# Is there a way to search for every place in a project where a certain method is used?

Tags: java, eclipse, search, methods

I have a project with a bunch of classes and I'm trying to figure out how I built it (yes, I've since become a much better commenter! :)

There's a method in one of my superclasses that I want to examine. I want to know where and how this method is used. Going through every class and searching manually will be tiresome and time consuming.

Is there any way to search across a project, particularly in subclasses, for a specific method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Eclipse, you can right click on the method and select References > Project from the context menu.

Comment: Yes I am using Eclipse, I should have mentioned that in my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

If you are using netbeans, you can right click on the method and select "find usages" (or) "call hierarchy"

Answer (score 3):

Are you using a Unix OS? If so, you could change into your project directory in the terminal and do something like `grep -rin "method_name" *`. That will recursively search your project directory, case insensitive and display the line numbers.

Comment: Except if you happened to look for e.g. `equals`,`put`, or `get` which are used (by totally unrelated code) all over the place. Seriously, for complex code you want help from an IDE.

Comment: True, but he didn't mention an IDE, so I figured it was possible he isn't using one.

Comment: I am using Eclipse, I should have mentioned that in my question. Thank you anyway!